# Why is my "sign in with google" (firebase + React) but not working when I deploy to AWS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I am building a react app with firebase. I am trying to use firebases auth features to allow users to sign in with google. this is the code I have.

```
<button 
    onClick={handleGoolgeSignIn} 
    className="btn btn-lg btn-google btn-block text-uppercase" 
    type="submit"
>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faGoogle} className="logo mr-2" /> Sign in with Google
</button>
```

```
const handleGoolgeSignIn = async e => {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    const result = await firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)
    const user = result.user
    firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).set({
        name: user.displayName,
        uid: user.uid
    })
}
```

```
import firebase from "firebase"
import "firebase/auth"

const config = {
    //private stuff
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(config);

export default firebase
```

when I use the app locally with `npm start` it works fine but when I deploy it to AWS amplify it doesn't work. how do I fix it?

[here](https://www.jotter-notes.xyz/auth/login) is the link to the deployed app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the console you should see an error saying that the domain doesn't have permission to do google sign in. what you need to do it go to the firebase console -> authentication -> sign-in methods and scroll down to authorized domains and add your domain